# How to check the length validation in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my input type in Angular

```
<td>
<input class="form-control" id="id_phone" name="mobileno" type="text" [(ngModel)]="mobileno"
 name="mobileno" placeholder="Enter MobileNo" />
</td>
```

Now I am trying to show an alert if this field in empty on click of button something like this:

```
  clickSubmit(event) {
    if (this.mobileno.length==0) {
      alert('Field is empty')
    } else {
      console.log('Everything is ok')
    } 
  }
```

But I am getting as error after hitting of button something like this, any sort of help is appreciated:

> PlaceorderComponent.html:293 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at PlaceorderComponent.push../src/app/placeorder/placeorder.component.ts.PlaceorderComponent.clickSubmit (placeorder.component.ts:56)

Comment: what is the initial value of this.name ?

Comment: Because `this.name` is undefined and you are calling `.length` on an undefiend variable. Make sure you have a valid value inside the variable.

Comment: If you are validating the model property [(mobileno)] then the validation should be this.mobileno.length==0?

Comment: Do `this.name?.length > 0` for your success case in your if. This will be a success if name is an object with a length property greater than 0 and fail in all other cases.

Comment: You realize Angular comes with built in validation for this scenario? Simply placing min-length attribute on the input would do the job. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validator-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are multiple ways to validate input before submitting *(as @Canolyb1 commented, you could look for [build in validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validator-functions))*.

In your way you should check the property that you have bind with your input: `mobileno`

You should also check for `null` and `undefined` values like this example:

```
if (this.mobileno && this.mobileno.length) {
  console.log('Everything is ok');
} else {
  alert('Field is empty');
}
```

Here I did a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsxtl8?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: ERROR in src/app/placeorder/placeorder.component.ts(56,25): error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/placeorder/placeorder.component.ts(56,32): error TS1005: ':' expected.

Comment: That's error message you copy and pasted is not helpful at all. My example is correct, I created a Stack-blitz to play around: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dsxtl8?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: If you have old node version maybe you could replace `?` with 
```if (!this.mobileno || !this.mobileno?.length)```